# Definition of the $p$-adic Metric

Tags: metric-spaces

> The $p$-adic metric on $\mathbb{Z}$ is defined as:
>
> $$d_{p}(x,y) =
> \begin{cases}
> 0,  & \text{if }\;x=y \\
> \frac{1}{p^{k(x,y)}}, & \text{if }\;x\neq y
> \end{cases}
> $$  where $p$ is prime and $k(x,y)=\max\{i: p^i|x-y\}$

If we have $d_{3}(17,22)$

So $k_{3}(17,22)=\max\{i:3^i|17-22\}=\max\{i:3^i|17-22\}=\max\{i:3^i|-5\}=0$

And $d_{3}(17,22)=\frac{1}{3^0}=1$ ?

Comment: Yes.  Numbers are close $p$-adically when their difference is divisible by a large power of $p$

Comment: I think the "if n is odd" clause is misplaced. If it is replaced with "if "$x \neq y$" then your calculation example is correct.

Comment: We look at x-y or $|x-y|$ or it does not matter?

Comment: It doesn't matter for divisibility in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Integers $a,b$ are close if $|a-b|_p$ is small, equivalently if $a = b$ in $\mathbb{Z}/p^k \mathbb{Z}$ with $k$ large. The idea is that the sequence $a_k = (a \bmod p^k)$ fully determinates an integer, thus we can see integers as such sequences $a_k \in \mathbb{Z}/p^k \mathbb{Z}$, $a_k \equiv a_m \bmod p^m , m \le k$, and this is a ring with the pointwise addition and multiplication $\bmod p^k$.